# Samba domain has multiple ips associated with it

Tags: samba, active-directory, domain

I have been setting up a samba DC but the same machine has a couple of docker containers running and it picked up the network interfaces as active, now the domain has 5 different ips that aren't what they are actually supposed to be. Nslookup output:

```
nslookup nexello.lan
Server:         192.168.0.100
Address:        192.168.0.100#53

Name:   nexello.lan
Address: 172.16.238.1
Name:   nexello.lan
Address: 172.17.0.1
Name:   nexello.lan
Address: 172.18.0.1
Name:   nexello.lan
Address: 172.19.0.1
Name:   nexello.lan
Address: 192.168.0.100
```

The only IP that should be associated with it is the last one. How can i remove the others?

Comment: Is samba perhabs listening on 0.0.0.0?

Comment: netstat --tulpn | grep ":53" says that samba is listening on tcp/udp 192.168.0.100:53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
samba-tool dns delete <host ip> nexello.lan @ A <record> -UAdministrator
```

and

```
samba-tool dns delete <host ip> nexello.lan <host name> A <record> -UAdministrator
```

Removed the extra records